# ModSecurity default installation running on IIS 10.0 with CRS rule set generating a lot of errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, mod-security, mod-security2

I have just installed ModSecurity on IIS 10.0 running on Windows 10. However even a "clean" install generates a lot of errors only by visiting the default IIS site.

By looking at `eventvwr` and making a single request I get a total of 14 new errors for a GET request to `localhost`.

Every event has the following description:

> The description for Event ID 1 from source ModSecurity cannot be
>   found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
>   your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
>   or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:

Eventdata:

```
[client ] ModSecurity: IPmatch: bad IPv4 specification "". [hostname "HOSTNAME"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "18158513704000290822"]

[client ] ModSecurity: Rule processing failed. [hostname "HOSTNAME"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "18158513704000290822"]

[client ] ModSecurity: Rule 15448555590 [id "981172"][file "C:\/Program Files/ModSecurity IIS/owasp_crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"][line "157"] - Execution error - PCRE limits exceeded (-8): (null). [hostname "HOSTNAME"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "18158513704000290822"]

[client ] ModSecurity: Rule 154485cd4a0 [id "981243"][file "C:\/Program Files/ModSecurity IIS/owasp_crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"][line "245"] - Execution error - PCRE limits exceeded (-8): (null). [hostname "HOSTNAME"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "18158513704000290822"]

[client ] ModSecurity: IPmatch: bad IPv4 specification "". [hostname "HOSTNAME"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "18158513704000290822"]

[client ] ModSecurity: Rule processing failed. [hostname "HOSTNAME"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "18158513704000290822"]

[client ] ModSecurity: Rule 15448555590 [id "981172"][file "C:\/Program Files/ModSecurity IIS/owasp_crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"][line "157"] - Execution error - PCRE limits exceeded (-8): (null). [hostname "HOSTNAME"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "18158513704000290822"]

[client ] ModSecurity: Rule 154485cd4a0 [id "981243"][file "C:\/Program Files/ModSecurity IIS/owasp_crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"][line "245"] - Execution error - PCRE limits exceeded (-8): (null). [hostname "HOSTNAME"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "18158513704000290822"]

[client ] ModSecurity: Rule 15448555590 [id "981172"][file "C:\/Program Files/ModSecurity IIS/owasp_crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"][line "157"] - Execution error - PCRE limits exceeded (-8): (null). [hostname "HOSTNAME"] [uri "/iisstart.htm"] [unique_id "18158513704000290822"]

[client ] ModSecurity: Rule 154485cd4a0 [id "981243"][file "C:\/Program Files/ModSecurity IIS/owasp_crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"][line "245"] - Execution error - PCRE limits exceeded (-8): (null). [hostname "HOSTNAME"] [uri "/iisstart.htm"] [unique_id "18158513704000290822"]

[client ] ModSecurity: collections_remove_stale: Failed to access DBM file "C:/inetpub/temp/ip": Access is denied. [hostname "HOSTNAME"] [uri "/iisstart.htm"] [unique_id "18158513704000290822"]

[client ] ModSecurity: collections_remove_stale: Failed to access DBM file "C:/inetpub/temp/global": Access is denied. [hostname "HOSTNAME"] [uri "/iisstart.htm"] [unique_id "18158513704000290822"]

[client ] ModSecurity: Rule 15448555590 [id "981172"][file "C:\/Program Files/ModSecurity IIS/owasp_crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"][line "157"] - Execution error - PCRE limits exceeded (-8): (null). [hostname "HOSTNAME"] [uri "/iisstart.png"] [unique_id "18158513704000290823"]

[client ] ModSecurity: Rule 154485cd4a0 [id "981243"][file "C:\/Program Files/ModSecurity IIS/owasp_crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"][line "245"] - Execution error - PCRE limits exceeded (-8): (null). [hostname "HOSTNAME"] [uri "/iisstart.png"] [unique_id "18158513704000290823"]
```

What I have done:

Installed [ModSecurity v2.9.1 for IIS MSI Installer - 64bits](https://modsecurity.org/download.html) and Visual Studio 2013 Runtime (vcredist).

Downloaded OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set (CRS) from https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs and put the folder in `C:\Program Files\ModSecurity IIS`. Changed the name `crs-setup.conf.example` to `crs-setup.conf`.

Under `\rules` I changed `REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf.example` and `RESPONSE-999-EXCLUSION-RULES-AFTER-CRS.conf.example` to not contain `.example`.

Modified `modsecurity_iis.conf` to the following:

```
Include modsecurity.conf
Include modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf
Include owasp_crs\base_rules\*.conf
#OWASP-Rules
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/crs-setup.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-901-INITIALIZATION.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-905-COMMON-EXCEPTIONS.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-910-IP-REPUTATION.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-911-METHOD-ENFORCEMENT.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-912-DOS-PROTECTION.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-913-SCANNER-DETECTION.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-921-PROTOCOL-ATTACK.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-930-APPLICATION-ATTACK-LFI.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-931-APPLICATION-ATTACK-RFI.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-932-APPLICATION-ATTACK-RCE.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-933-APPLICATION-ATTACK-PHP.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-943-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SESSION-FIXATION.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/RESPONSE-950-DATA-LEAKAGES.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/RESPONSE-951-DATA-LEAKAGES-SQL.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/RESPONSE-952-DATA-LEAKAGES-JAVA.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/RESPONSE-953-DATA-LEAKAGES-PHP.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/RESPONSE-954-DATA-LEAKAGES-IIS.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/RESPONSE-959-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/RESPONSE-980-CORRELATION.conf
include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/RESPONSE-999-EXCLUSION-RULES-AFTER-CRS.conf
```

Restarted IIS and then checked Event Viewer. What have I missed or is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the description I found this:

> This is just an warning. That is actually the ModSecurity letting you
>   know something about a given request. The "windows description" of the
>   event can be ignored. Look at the content...

https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/issues/877#issuecomment-267712103

```
1. Execution error - PCRE limits exceeded (-8): (null):
```

Modified `modsecurity.conf` values to the following:

```
SecPcreMatchLimit 500000
SecPcreMatchLimitRecursion 500000
```

Instead of reading data from EventLog I started using Audit log instead. Can be enabled via `modsecurity.conf`. Set format to `JSON` instead of `Native` to read the log file programatically. Remember to give the user `IIS_IUSRS` access to the logs folder and files.

```
# -- Audit log configuration -------------------------------------------------

# Log the transactions that are marked by a rule, as well as those that
# trigger a server error (determined by a 5xx or 4xx, excluding 404,  
# level response status codes).
#

SecAuditLogFormat JSON

SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly
SecAuditLogRelevantStatus "^(?:5|4(?!04))"

# Log everything we know about a transaction.
SecAuditLogParts ABIJDEFHZ

# Use a single file for logging. This is much easier to look at, but
# assumes that you will use the audit log only ocassionally.
#
SecAuditLogType Serial
SecAuditLog c:\inetpub\logs\modsec_audit.log

# Specify the path for concurrent audit logging.
SecAuditLogStorageDir c:\inetpub\logs\
```